# Netbeans Makefile macro available in code

Tags: c, netbeans, makefile, mplab

I'm building a C project in MPLAB X (based on Netbeans) and I need to define a macro in the Makefile that should be available in code or the other way around...

This is for version control.

Example:

in code:

`#define VERSION "1.1.0"`

in makefile

`VERSION=1.1.0`

`@cp "${ImagePath}" build_${VERSION}.bin`

What I needed was to define the VERSION macro in ONE place only!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you need, what you have and what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @EtanReisner, just edited the question with an example. Hope it's clear

Comment: Does defining `VERSION=1.1.0` in the makefile and then using `-DVERSION='$(VERSION)'` on your compilation lines do what you are trying to do?